# is it possible to add the vtk library to jython 2.7.3 ?(non-native python libraries)

Tags: python, java, jython, vtk

I use jython and I'd like to add the vtk library so that I can run my python code (code that uses vtk modules) on eclipse.

I installed jypthon and then I typed the command jython -m pip install vtk and I got an error ImportError: No module named _winreg